# Let $X_1,X_2...X_n $ be a random sample from a $N(\theta ,\theta^2 )$ distribution, where $\theta >0$ is unknown.

Tags: probability-distributions, statistical-inference, parameter-estimation

Let $X_1,X_2...X_n $ be a random sample from a $N(\theta ,\theta^2 )$ distribution, where $\theta >0$ is unknown.Let $T_1=\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i$ and $T_2=\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i^2$

Which of the following statements are correct?

$(A)=\dfrac{T_1^2}{n^2} $ is unbiased for $\theta^2$

$(B)=\dfrac{T_2}{2n} $ is unbiased for $\theta^2$

$(C)=\dfrac{T_1^2}{n^2} $ is consistent for $\theta^2$

$(D)=\dfrac{T_2}{2n} $ is consistent for $\theta^2$

The way I tried

$(A)\implies \dfrac{T_1}{n}=\bar X $ squaring both sides $\dfrac{T_1^2}{n^2}=\bar X^2$

If I take expectation I get $E(\bar X^2)=\theta^2$

$(B)\implies E(T_2)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}E(X_i^2)=n(V(X)+E(X)^2)=n(2\theta^2)$

$E\bigg(\dfrac{T_2}{2n}\bigg)=\theta^2$

Although this question has been answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2603347/consistent-and-unbiased-estimator-of-theta-2). But in option (A) I am making some mistake and I am not able to figure out.

Comment: Use $\bar X\sim N(\theta, \theta^2/n)$ to find $E(\bar X^2)$.

Comment: We cannot identify where your mistake is, if you don´t post your process of calculation.

Comment: @StubbornAtom Ohh I see $E(\bar X^2)=V(\bar X)+E(\bar X)^2=\frac{\theta^2}{n}+\theta^2$ Which is biased thanks man.